# Am getting 'Field 'mui_profile_id' doesn't have a default value' while try to establish a OneToMany relationship in JPA

Tags: mysql, jpa

I am trying to establish a OneToMany relationship between User and UserIdentification where many identification records are to be saved against a user profile. am trying to save the mu_profile_id in the UserIdentification table as a foreign key named 'mui_profile_id'.

please find the below table structure.
List of User identification details are stored in user against a list UserIdentification entities.

CREATE TABLE `a2b_mstr_user` (
  `mu_id` int(15) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `mu_profile_id` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `mu_user_id` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `mu_password` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `mu_first_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `mu_last_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `mu_gender` varchar(1) NOT NULL,
  `mu_nationality` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `mu_date_of_birth` date NOT NULL,
  `mu_place_of_birth` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mu_notes` tinytext,
  `mu_status` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mu_locked` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mu_unsuc_log_attmpts` int(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`mu_id`),
  KEY `last_name_ind` (`mu_last_name`),
  KEY `profile_id_ind` (`mu_profile_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB

User Identification Table

CREATE TABLE `a2b_mstr_user_identification` (
  `mui_identfcn_id` int(15) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `mui_profile_id` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `mui_document_type` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `mui_document_category` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mui_document_no` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `mui_country` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mui_state` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mui_valid_from` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `mui_valid_to` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `mui_status` varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Y' COMMENT 'to determine the document is active or not. ''Y'' if ''Active'' and ''N'' if not active.',
  PRIMARY KEY (`mui_identfcn_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `DOCUMENT_NO_IND` (`mui_document_no`),
  KEY `USER_IDENTIFICATION_FK` (`mui_profile_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `USER_IDENTIFICATION_FK` FOREIGN KEY (`mui_profile_id`) REFERENCES `a2b_mstr_user` (`mu_profile_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB

and the entities for User.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="A2B_MSTR_USER")
public class User extends BaseEntity{

    @Column(name="mu_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    protected String muId;

    @Column(name="mu_profile_id")
    protected String profileId;

    @Column(name="mu_user_id")
    @NotEmpty
    protected String userId;

    @Column(name="mu_password")
    protected String password;

    @Column(name="mu_first_name")
    @NotEmpty
    protected String firstName;

    @Column(name="mu_last_name")
    @NotEmpty
    protected String lastName;

    @Column(name="mu_gender")
    @NotEmpty
    protected String gender;

    @Column(name="mu_nationality")
    @NotEmpty
    protected String nationality;

    @Column(name="mu_date_of_birth")
    protected Date dateOfBirth;

    @Column(name="mu_place_of_birth")
    protected String placeOfBirth;

    @Column(name="mu_notes")
    protected String notes;

    @Column(name="mu_status")
    protected Short status;

    @Column(name="mu_locked")
    protected boolean isLocked;

    @Column(name="mu_unsuc_log_attmpts")
    protected int unSucLogonAttmpts;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,cascade = CascadeType.ALL,mappedBy="user")
    protected UserContact userContact;

    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL,mappedBy="user")
    protected List<UserAttachment>  userAttachments;

    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="mui_profile_id",insertable=true,updatable=true)
    protected List<UserIdentification>  userIdentificationDetails;

    @PrePersist
    protected void prePersist(){
        if(getProfileId()==null){
        setProfileId(new IdGenerator(10).nextString().toUpperCase());
        }
    }

    public String getMuId() {
        return muId;
    }

    public void setMuId(String muId) {
        this.muId = muId;
    }

    public String getProfileId() {
        return profileId;
    }

    public void setProfileId(String profileId) {
        this.profileId = profileId;
    }

    public String getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(String userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getGender() {
        return gender;
    }

    public void setGender(String gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    public String getNationality() {
        return nationality;
    }

    public void setNationality(String nationality) {
        this.nationality = nationality;
    }

    public Date getDateOfBirth() {
        return dateOfBirth;
    }

    public void setDateOfBirth(Date dateOfBirth) {
        this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
    }

    public String getPlaceOfBirth() {
        return placeOfBirth;
    }

    public void setPlaceOfBirth(String placeOfBirth) {
        this.placeOfBirth = placeOfBirth;
    }

    public String getNotes() {
        return notes;
    }

    public void setNotes(String notes) {
        this.notes = notes;
    }


    public UserContact getUserContact() {
        return userContact;
    }

    public void setUserContact(UserContact userContact) {
        this.userContact = userContact;

    }

    public Short getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(Short status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public boolean isLocked() {
        return isLocked;
    }

    public void setLocked(boolean isLocked) {
        this.isLocked = isLocked;
    }

    public int getUnSucLogonAttmpts() {
        return unSucLogonAttmpts;
    }

    public void setUnSucLogonAttmpts(int unSucLogonAttmpts) {
        this.unSucLogonAttmpts = unSucLogonAttmpts;
    }

    public List<UserAttachment> getUserAttachments() {
        return userAttachments;
    }

    public void setUserAttachments(List<UserAttachment> userAttachments) {
        this.userAttachments = userAttachments;
    }


    public List<UserIdentification> getUserIdentificationDetails() {
        return userIdentificationDetails;
    }

    public void setUserIdentificationDetails(ArrayList<UserIdentification> userIdentificationDetails) {
        this.userIdentificationDetails = userIdentificationDetails;
    }


}
```

And the Entity for UserIdentification as follows.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="A2B_MSTR_USER_IDENTIFICATION")
public class UserIdentification extends BaseEntity {

    @Column(name="mui_identfcn_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    protected Integer identificationId;

    @Column(name="mui_document_type")
    protected String documentType;

    @Column(name="mui_document_category")
    protected String documentCategory;

    @Column(name="mui_document_no")
    protected String documentNo;

    @Column(name="mui_country")
    protected String country;

    @Column(name="mui_state")
    protected String state;

    @Column(name="mui_valid_from")
    protected Date validFrom;

    @Column(name="mui_valid_to")
    protected Date validTo;

    @Column(name="mui_status")
    protected String status;


    public Integer getIdentificationId() {
        return identificationId;
    }

    public void setIdentificationId(Integer identificationId) {
        this.identificationId = identificationId;
    }

    public String getDocumentType() {
        return documentType;
    }

    public void setDocumentType(String documentType) {
        this.documentType = documentType;
    }

    public String getDocumentCategory() {
        return documentCategory;
    }

    public void setDocumentCategory(String documentCategory) {
        this.documentCategory = documentCategory;
    }

    public String getDocumentNo() {
        return documentNo;
    }

    public void setDocumentNo(String documentNo) {
        this.documentNo = documentNo;
    }

    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }

    public String getState() {
        return state;
    }

    public void setState(String state) {
        this.state = state;
    }

    public Date getValidFrom() {
        return validFrom;
    }

    public void setValidFrom(Date validFrom) {
        this.validFrom = validFrom;
    }

    public Date getValidTo() {
        return validTo;
    }

    public void setValidTo(Date validTo) {
        this.validTo = validTo;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }



    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "UserIdentification [identificationId=" + identificationId + ", documentType=" + documentType
                + ", documentCategory=" + documentCategory + ", documentNo=" + documentNo + ", country=" + country
                + ", state=" + state + ", validFrom=" + validFrom + ", validTo=" + validTo + ", status=" + status
                + ", user=" + "]";
    }



}
```

When I am trying to save it using JPA, am getting the error Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Field 'mui_profile_id' doesn't have a default value.

Comment: Have you provided any value to 'profileId' while saving your jpa entity ? If you haven't, then error will definitely come as there is no default value to be set in database if you haven't provided one.

Comment: Yes. Profile Id is generated by  @PrePersist prePersist() in user and then this profileID has been given as foreign key in UserIdentification table.

Comment: @Prasad Kharkar Do I need to set the value of foreign key before I save the user. Does JPA set this?

Comment: I would like to see the code where you are setting the relationships.

Comment: What is the IdGenarator class? It is strange that you are using PrePersist method for geenrating id. Why aren't you using Id generator mechanisms in JPA ?

Comment: I am setting this in User Enity as follows: @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
 @JoinColumn(name="mui_profile_id",insertable=true,updatable=true)
 protected List<UserIdentification>  userIdentificationDetails;
 
 @PrePersist
 protected void prePersist(){
  if(getProfileId()==null){
  setProfileId(new IdGenerator(10).nextString().toUpperCase());
  }
 }

Comment: My requirement was to generate a alphanumeric ID which is a random alpha numeric key consists of characters and numbers. So I thought of using custom Id generator class.Is there any better method to do this?